# How do you tell if the value of a number text box goes positive

Tags: javascript, jquery

Probably a simple answer but for some reason I can not find the answer even with a simple Google search.

I have number text box that I want to know if the value of the number goes up or increments, I want to do something and if the value goes down or decrements I want it to something else.

This is the simple JS I have right now but right now I am just looking for if the text box goes above 1.  I want to actually know if the value actually incremented. 
I am using jQuery.

I have some simple buttons incrementing the value of the textbox by 1 or drecrementing by 1.

You will see the section below where I need some help with as noted.

=============

**EDIT:**

Added a JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4v6wb2ys/2/

You will see on the left is a total of attendees. This controls the number that can be controlled on the right.  My issue is partially the CART part at the bottom of the right panel in 'Result' in the Fiddle.
The Cart does not add items to the Cart as needed. It adds some but then on the decrement it adds more items until the value of the textbox hits 0. Then it removes them. 
This is the main part of my question I am asking here. I need to add an take away items as the values in the right panel are incremented and decremented. 
I know my JS is pretty ugly. IF there are improvements, please let me know how to fix them.

=======================

```
    $(".AddMinusButton").on('click touchstart', function (event) { 

        var $button = $(this);
        var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input.attendeeQuantityInput").val();
        var newVal = oldValue;

       //Increment and decrement the value of the textbox

        if ($button.text() == "+") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;

    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue >= 1) {
            newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        }
    }



     $InputItem = $('.ProductDetailPage').find("input[data-attendee='" + gaData + "']"); 
         $InputItem.each(function() {

      //I have some values for vars $list and li but those are not important for this.

     //THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE ANSWER TO MY QUESTION
      if ($(this).val() >= 1) {   //This line should probably be were the 'IF value increments'
                $list.append(li);
            } else {
                $list.find("li." + attendee + parentSection).remove();
            }
     });
  });
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have? `foo > 0` shows if your variable is positive. `foo < 0`, negative.

Comment: can you do a fiddle?

Comment: You want *to know if the value has been incremented or decremented* when you're the one explicitly do so? -- `newMemVal = parseFloat(oldMemValue) + 1` ... `newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;` :/

Comment: @philtune it is not if the number itself if positive, I would like to know if the value increases or decreases not if the value is a positive number.

Comment: @PeterKA, yes that is correct

Comment: It seems like you're missing the obvious. Reread PeterKA's comment.

Comment: I don't get the logic, why you don't decalre a global var (in your function you reset each time the old value), then check it and at the end update the oldvalue with the new one?

Comment: definitely seems far more complex than is needed. Some simple state storing would cut out a lot of this code.

Comment: Added a Fiddle example

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sequence:

```
....
....
var newVal = oldValue;
var incremented; //declare a new variable;
....
....
newMemVal = parseFloat(oldMemValue) + 1;
incremented = true; //after you increment the value set the variable to true
.....
.....
newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
incremented = false; //after you increment the value set the variable to false
....
....
if ( incremented ) { //Now you know what you did!! 'incremented' remembers for you.
    $list.append(li);
....
....
```